# Too Many winlogon.exe LogonUI.exe csrss.exe open on server?

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I just had to restart my content server because it bogged out.  Everything was fine after i restarted IIS and SQL Server, but then i opened the task manager and found the following.  I've never seen this before, i'm hoping it's not a virus of somesort.  Any info on this would be appreciated.

Command lines are:
        winlogon.exe = winlogon.exe

```
    logonUI.exe = LogonUI.exe /flags:0x0

    csrss.exe = see image below
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the command line? (View, Select Columns)

Comment: winlogon.exe = winlogon.exe
logonUI.exe = LogonUI.exe /flags:0x0

Comment: Is this a machine used as a terminal services server?

Comment: its a web/ftp server.. hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem on one of my servers - it turned out to be caused by an attempt to get into the server through Remote Desktop/Terminal Services - either a brute-force or massive dictionary attack (every RDP logon attempt causes LogonUI to spawn). Check your System and Security event logs, they'll contain more information (such as the originating IP of any failed remote logon attempts).

Comment: Tip: if you are concerned about the resources consumed by these processes, you can change the settings to require NLA. This won't stop brute force attacks, but will prevent failed logon attempts from spawning the processes.

Answer (score 3):

I found it was the morto virus

http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/Threat/Encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?Name=Virus:Win32/Morto.A

Malwarebytes fixes it.